# Make a time series data in R

Tags: r, time, series

I have a numeric variable and a date which includes just year and month, I was wondering how I can have a time series data.

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4,55,66,7,88,88,99,99,55,56,6,7,7,8)
Date<-c("1999-01","1999-02","1999-01","1999-10","1999-10","1999-01","1999-01","1999-11","1999-11","1999-01","1999-05","1999-03","1999-12","1999-4","1999-01","1999-12","1999-2")
Data<-data.frame(A,Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

May be we could use `read.zoo`

```
library(zoo)
read.zoo(Data, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%Y-%m", index.column = 2)
```